# POST request on form submit ember.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am totally green in Ember.JS. I’ve made simple adoption shelter application with Ember tutorials as I am using ember on front end, and Strapi (Node.JS) as an Headless CMS. I have all the endpoints and my ember front is successfully fetching data with GET method via JavaScript’s fetch. However, I want to allow users to create POST requests based on form submit, I can’t find any good example or tutorial how to properly make an post request on form submit in ember.js, could you please help me with figuring out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/formdata_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent
- https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/template-lifecycle-dom-and-modifiers/#toc_event-handlers

I think you could submit a form via:

```
ember g component my-form -gc
```

And then in that component

```js
// app/components/my-form.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class MyForm extends Component {

  submit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let data = new FormData(event.target);

    await fetch('your url', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

  }
}
```

```
{{! app/components/my-form.hbs }}
<form {{on 'click' this.submit}}>
  ...
</form>
```